# Vlc , Apache2 and iMX6 (Linux)

Tags: linux, apache, stream, vlc, imx6

I am using yocto project image that  i insert my sd cart. I installed vlc features in to my image  and I have project to stream video from the apache2 web server , the necessary code is implemented in the web server html code like ;

`<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="100%" 
height="100%" id="vlc" loop="yes"autoplay="yes" target="http://79.145.55.192:8181/udp/239.0.5.185:8208/"></embed>`

  I have solved the vlc plugin issiue but I cant see anything in my webserver  about stream ,it is not opening . 
Is there any thing that I m missing to add ? 
Can you help me about that issue?

Thanks 
Best Regards 
Mustafa

Comment: I didn't see any problem in your codes. but I guess if you use this plugin you have to install VLC plugin or media player on your sd card. I m not sure...